Separate listing counter and name for "Run Output" type of listing
I want to define a new listing environment for a “program output” kind of listing via \lstnewenvironment. I also want a new counter for program output listings that's separate from regular listings, but still to include the chapter number.
Based on some answers I found elsewhere online, I came up with what's below.  The problem is that the parameters following \begin{progoutput}, i.e., [caption={...}, label=out:args, style=float] aren't being passed "through" to the underlying lstlisting because there's no caption and the progoutput content isn't floating to the next page (instead, it's being split across pages).
Why doesn't at the Run Output: show up?
Can options be passed through?
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language=C,
  abovecaptionskip=\medskipamount,
  aboveskip=\baselineskip,
  belowcaptionskip=0pt,
  belowskip=\baselineskip,
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  breaklines=true,
  captionpos=b,
  floatplacement=hbt!,
  keepspaces=true,
  keywordstyle=\lst@ifdisplaystyle\bfseries\fi\normalsize,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  tabsize=2,
  xleftmargin=.4in
}

% See <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/729832/340554>
\lstdefinestyle{float}{
  aboveskip=0pt,
  belowskip=0pt,
  float
}

\newcounter{progoutputcounter}[chapter]

\lstnewenvironment{progoutput}
  {
    \stepcounter{progoutputcounter}
    \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Run Output}
  }
  {\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Listing}}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{A Chapter}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={A First Program}, style=float]
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf( "hello, world!\n" );
}
\end{lstlisting}

\lipsum[3][1-7]
Output \ref{out:args}

\begin{progoutput}[caption={\lstinline|args| output}, label=out:args, style=float]
$ cc -o args args.c
$ args hello, world
0 args
1 hello,
2 world
\end{progoutput}

\end{document}


Usage of counter lstlisting is hard coded in \lst@MakeCaption. But you can change the value of the counter in the begin and the end code of the new environment.
One more note: \lstnewenvironment does not automatically add an optional argument to the definition of the new environment. So if you want an optional argument to be able to set listings options you need to add it yourself and also the handling of that option. See also the pascalx example in section “4.5 Environment” of the listings documentation. And you don't need to redefine \lstlistingname again in the end code, because the redefinition from the begin code is local to the environment. I have taken both into account in my examples below.
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language=C,
  abovecaptionskip=\medskipamount,
  aboveskip=\baselineskip,
  belowcaptionskip=0pt,
  belowskip=\baselineskip,
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  breaklines=true,
  captionpos=b,
  floatplacement=hbt!,
  keepspaces=true,
  keywordstyle=\lst@ifdisplaystyle\bfseries\fi\normalsize,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  tabsize=2,
  xleftmargin=.4in
}

% See <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/729832/340554>
\lstdefinestyle{float}{
  aboveskip=0pt,
  belowskip=0pt,
  float
}

\newcounter{progoutputcounter}[chapter]
\newcounter{lstlistingwas}
\lstnewenvironment{progoutput}[1][]
{%
  \lstset{#1}%
    \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Run Output}% this is local to the environment
    \setcounter{lstlistingwas}{\value{lstlisting}}% this is global
    \setcounter{lstlisting}{\value{progoutputcounter}}% this is global
  }
  {%
    \setcounter{progoutputcounter}{\value{lstlisting}}% this is global
    \setcounter{lstlisting}{\value{lstlistingwas}}% this is global
  }

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{A Chapter}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={A First Program}, style=float]
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf( "hello, world!\n" );
}
\end{lstlisting}

\lipsum[3][1-7]
Output \ref{out:args} or \ref{out:args2}.

\begin{progoutput}[caption={\lstinline{args} output},label=out:args,style=float]
$ cc -o args args.c
$ args hello, world
0 args
1 hello,
2 world
\end{progoutput}

\begin{progoutput}[caption={second \lstinline{args} output},label=out:args2,style=float]
$ cc -o args args.c
$ args world, hello
0 args
1 world,
2 hello
\end{progoutput}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={A Second Program}, style=float]
int main() {
  exit(1)
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}


Note, this still uses \thelstlisting for the output of the counter.
An alternative could be:
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language=C,
  abovecaptionskip=\medskipamount,
  aboveskip=\baselineskip,
  belowcaptionskip=0pt,
  belowskip=\baselineskip,
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  breaklines=true,
  captionpos=b,
  floatplacement=hbt!,
  keepspaces=true,
  keywordstyle=\lst@ifdisplaystyle\bfseries\fi\normalsize,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  tabsize=2,
  xleftmargin=.4in
}

% See <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/729832/340554>
\lstdefinestyle{float}{
  aboveskip=0pt,
  belowskip=0pt,
  float
}

\newcounter{progoutputcounter}
\counterwithin{progoutputcounter}{chapter}% also redefine \theprogoutputcounter depending on chapter
\makeatletter
\lstnewenvironment{progoutput}[1][]
{%
  \lstset{#1}%
    \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Run Output}% this is local to the environment
    \let\c@lstlisting\c@progoutputcounter% use the progoutputcounter, whenever using the lstlisting counter
    \let\thelstlisting\theprogoutputcounter% same for the output of the counter
  }
  {%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{A Chapter}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={A First Program}, style=float]
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf( "hello, world!\n" );
}
\end{lstlisting}

\lipsum[3][1-7]
Output \ref{out:args} or \ref{out:args2}.

\begin{progoutput}[caption={\lstinline{args} output},label=out:args,style=float]
$ cc -o args args.c
$ args hello, world
0 args
1 hello,
2 world
\end{progoutput}

\begin{progoutput}[caption={second \lstinline{args} output},label=out:args2,style=float]
$ cc -o args args.c
$ args world, hello
0 args
1 world,
2 hello
\end{progoutput}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={A Second Program}, style=float]
int main() {
  exit(1)
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}

Here the change of \l@lstlisting and \thelstlisting is again local to the usage of the new environment.
Note: In the second example I've also changed
\newcounter{progoutputcounter}[chapter]

into
\newcounter{progoutputcounter}
\counterwithin{progoutputcounter}{chapter}

Without this change \theprogoutputcounter would not be prefixed by \thechapter., but only reset when chapter is increased. \counterwithin adds the counter to the reset list and redefines \the… to prefix it by the parent counter. Without this change the output of the second example would be:

